# SSRS chart does not show y-axis data labels when values are very small (<1)

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have chart that plots values of Y-axis less than 1 (0.1, 0.24, etc).

When the chart is built,  Y-axis label just shows 0 at the origin and no other values along the axis.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a little ugly.    Data series labels show up with the correct % signs, but the % signs do not show up on the Y axis.

Y axis:  set Y axis range from 1-100 (or 1-120 so there is room to display the data labels that say 100%)  Make sure you set your tick marks to Auto or a number between 1 and 100, otherwise you'll get one long bar of tick marks running all the way up the y axis.

Data series:  on the series tab, change your Value Field formula to multiply your data series by 100.

Data series labels:  on the series data label properties window > general tab, copy the formula from your data series Value Field into the Label Data value field.  round it to 0 decimal points and add &"%" to the end to concatenate a percent to the end of it.

That way the right numbers display for my data series and my Y axis, but the % just doesn't show up on the Y axis.  not perfect yet.  and too much work.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seems this happens in SSRS 2005 and not 2008. You can fix this by right clicking on your chart and going to properties. It should bring up the full Chart Properties, go to the Y Axis tab and set Major Gridlines at a value like .25/.5 or whatever you want.